# How to grow and shrink image based on the window size?

Tags: html, css

I want the image and text to display on the same line, and have the image shrink and stay inline as the window shrinks.

Below is the CSS code. I want the image to shrink as the window shrinks.

```css
.body1 {
  display: flex;
 
}
```

Any suggestions would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Give the img container a percentage width and the img element width=100%.
For example if you had 3 images on every line with 10px margin, set img container width to width: calc(100%/3 - 20px) and so on. Same goes with the text, it depends how many element you want on each line and then do the calculations accordingly.